# Scroll Android ListView to top without scroll animation

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm using this code to scroll a `ListView` to top:

```
list.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(0, 0, 0);
```

the function declaration is:

```
smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(int position, int offset, int duration)
```

Despite the duration is 0, I can still see the scroll happening

Is there a way to set the scroll position to 0 without seeing it scrolling?

BTW `list.setSelection(0);` or `list.scrollTo(0, 0);` didn't work for me at all

**EDIT: Solved using this code:**

```
list.requestFocusFromTouch();
list.setSelection(0);
```